# Specifying step widths for numerical integration in MATLAB

Tags: integration, numerical-methods, matlab, math-software

When numerically integrating a function using MATLAB's `integral` or `quadgk` one specifies the function with the input parameter `x`, the `xmin` and `xmax`. $$ \int_{xmin}^{xmax} f(x) dx$$
Numerically this should look like one of these sums: 
$$1: \sum_{n=xmin}^{N=xmax} f(n)*s<n \\
2:\sum_{n=xmin}^{N=xmax} \omega_i f(n)<n 
$$ 
where $s$ is a constant step width and $\omega_i$ is a weight for the Gaussian quadrature.

When using `integral` or `quadgk` I encountered some problems:

1. How can I specify the maximum step width (and the amount of summation points) for the sum? As far as I understand `integral` calculates this to get a specific accuracy that can also be set using `AbsTol, RelTol`, but for my function it doesn't work well, so I would like to test it by reducing the amount of the step width manually.
2. When specifying and increasing the accuracy using `AbsTol` the amount of summation points should probably also increase. So if I want an accuracy of $10^{-15}$ there should be more summation points then for an accuracy of $10^{-10}$. I would like the `integral` (or similar) algorithm to output a vector of these summation points – how can this be done?
3. Which integration algorithm works with non-equidistant step widths?

Please let me know if something is not clear.

Comment: What do you mean by nodes?  Do you mean to say that you want to specify how many rectangles are used in a Riemann sum to numerically integrate your function?  Or something similar to this?

Comment: My question has been edited. could you please remove the "on hold" status?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question is rather complicated to answer and mentions two different functions. In essence you want to specify a maximum evaluation time to the functions.

1

Using the supplied workings of MATLAB, you cannot supply the maximum step width to either `integral` or `quadgk`. I would actually advise against it, you should rather set a maximal number of subdivisions. If you open `./private/integralCalc/` from `integral` file position, you will see the inner workings of the integration. The original [a,b] interval is split into `INITIALINTERVALCOUNT` subintervals (set to 10 by `./private/integralParseArgs`) which can then be subdivided further based on local errors (this is an adaptive quadrature). There is a variable called `MAXINTERVALCOUNT` that sets the maximal number of subdivisions. Since the `integral` function is able to integrate up to infinity it might be wiser to set a maximum number of intervals rather than a maximal step size. In the case of `quadgk`, you can directly set the maximum number of intervals in the option structure.

2

Assuming that you're interested in `integral` you should look into the `subs` variable of the `iterateScalarValued` and `iterateArrayValued` functions of `integralCalc` or the `subs` variable of `quadgk`. There is a line where some parts of `subs` are removed (since they have sufficient precision), you could simply add the removed subintervals to some output variable.

3

This part of the question does not really makes sense for adaptive integration. Both `integral` and `quadgk` use non constant stepsize due to division of subintervals to minimize errors, which is why you should set a maximum number of subdivisions rather than maximum step size.

Comment: thanks - that was very helpfull! I have applied some adjustments to the integral function. The `subs` variable didn't help me a lot but the rest was a great help!